# Translate this 'for' loop in VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am currently trying to use a VB.NET function in C#. I have to translate the following from VB.NET to C#:

```
For index = LBound(CollectionChannelPanel.EkItems) To UBound(CollectionChannelPanel.EkItems)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `LBound` and `UBound` equivalents are mentioned in: [VB to C# Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722896/vb-to-c-sharp-functions)

Answer (score 7):

```
foreach(var item in CollectionChannelPanel.EkItems)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks moo-juice, but after i posted i just found this site http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/

Comment: Should still accept his answer as correct, since it is. Hit it with an up arrow and check that mark. =)

Answer (score 4):

Complement to Moo-Juice's answer:

```
for (int index = 0; index < CollectionChannelPanel.EkItems.Length; i++) {
}
```

which would be closer to your VB.NET code. (Maybe you're interested in the "index" and not in the item itself...)

Comment: thanks roman, i was more interested in the index, I figured it out, it was:
 for (index = (CollectionChannelPanel.EkItems).GetLowerBound(0); (index <= (CollectionChannelPanel.EkItems).GetUpperBound(0)); index++)

Comment: That's the problem with code translators, they don't actually improve the code.  If you prefer taking advice from a dumb Lisp machine instead of a smart programmer then that's up to you.

Comment: The code generator assumed that "UBound" and "LBound" were functions defined by you, and therefore available in any case. It didn't know that they're language specific aliases and only available to VB (they're defined in Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information).

Comment: Yeah I seen that Roman, but I kind of knew that they were builtin VB functions, thanks for the heads up though :)

Comment: You could have also just Google "C# for loops". =)