# ASP.NET C# equivalent of vbScript/VB LEFT in the example

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I've inherited 1 page of a web app to update and the old classic ASP version used the LEFT, RIGHT and MID functions a great deal. The updated app uses C# ASP.NET. Is there a way to either import the VB left, right and mid functions or a function that will simulate those functions.

The C# substring function seems to return an error if the string is shorter than the length parameter under C#. (Don't make fun of my C# code, I hardly use C#). Filling in the with the needed code would be awesome

```
<%@ Page language="c#" %>
<%@ Import namespace="Microsoft.VisualBasic"%>

<script runat="server" language="C#">

protected virtual string Auth(string uid)
{
String xml;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["uid"]))
{

System.Data.DataTable dtTable = new System.Data.DataTable();


System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

string query = "SELECT id, blah, blah from users WHERE left(secretkey,30)='" + Request["uid"] + "'"; <--need to know how to use left function here

blah blah blah...

</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>blah</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server"><% Page_Load(null, null); %></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The left function as you are using it is SQL, not c#.

Comment: so what you expect.. if its shorter then what should happen?

Comment: Following should help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722896/vb-to-c-sharp-functions

Comment: Comecme is correct. i dont need to worry about the left in C#, I can just use the LEFT function in the sql query. Please add that as an answer so I can give you credit

Comment: (this won't solve your question, but) You should be using parameterized queries.  E.g. http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: @TimS have given great suggestion also don't forget to Close your SqlConnection

Comment: @HatSoft Yep, I'd suggest `using (var conn = ...)` to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I already said in my remark on the wuestion, you are using SQL's `left` function, so it doesn't matter if you are using vb or c#.

Answer (score 0):

From the linked question from my comment,

```
Left()       = "string".Substring(0, length)
Right()      = "string".Substring("string".Length - desiredLength)
Mid()        = "string".Substring(start, length)
```

Answer (score 0):

**First problem** is that you aren't calling left in C# at all in this example.

string query = "SELECT id, blah, blah from users WHERE left(secretkey,30)='" + Request["uid"] + "'";

you are using the left function in sql server which is why you aren't getting any error in the web page see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx

**Second problem** is that secretkey is in the table so unless you retrieve its value to the client you could never use VB's left function on it

So I am going to assume this was just a super bad example and you are looking for something more like this.

var secretkey = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"

string query = "Select blah, blah from users Where secretkey =" + secretkey.Substring(0,30)